# Creating a resource file in Linux assembly

Tags: linux, assembly

How would I go about having a resource file in Linux assembly? I would like to read it byte by byte and everything that I have found has been with Windows. I have just started learning assembly and it seems to have very few good resources. I use the NASM assembler.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: This question is very similar to this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235175/how-do-i-add-contents-of-text-file-as-a-section-in-an-elf-file) . One of the answers show how you can use NASM (one of the examples) using `objcopy` . Although it is about text files it also works with binary files just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't. Linux doesn't embed resource data in executables like Windows does.

It's technically possible to embed data into an executable -- [the easiest way is by using `objcopy`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967):

```
objcopy --input binary \
    --output elf32-i386 \
    --binary-architecture i386 \
    data.bin data.o
```

However, don't expect anything except your own executable to read that data. This isn't how you attach an icon to a GUI executable, for instance; that's done using entirely different methods.

Comment: How would I read the file? The example on your link was in C.

Comment: So in NASM, you'll need `extern _binary_data_txt_start` followed by `mov rsi, _binary_data_txt_start` to get a pointer to the data in `rsi`.  Or `mov al, [_binary_data_txt_start]` to get the first byte in `al`.