# gcc asm: keyword for importing string from text file as a resource (rodata)?

Tags: gcc, assembly, mips

I'm beginner in `asm` (`mips`) and I would like to import a large string into my program in order to displaying it (this has to be done before compilation).
For simplicity reasons, I don't like to put the whole string on the program source code.

How is it possible to accomplish this?
Is there any keyword or macro which I can use?

Comment: Why would you want to use asm? Where do you want to put the string?

Comment: @MarcGlisse Why does this matter?

Comment: Import from outside the code is an OS operation. You need to call the proper function from some lib like stdio.

Comment: @Ripi2 What I need is to be done before compilation.

Comment: @Ripi2 I need to import a string (part of the program) but using the text file as a named resource.

Comment: You can use preprocessor directives (#include) in an asm file, if your compilation process preprocesses the file before assembling it (for instance if the file is named something.S and compiled with gcc).

Comment: This question and the answer seem to be closely related including getting it into an RODATA section. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235175/how-do-i-add-contents-of-text-file-as-a-section-in-an-elf-file  Acouple samples of using the data from both _C_ and NASM is provided.

Comment: Is it ok if the file holding the string starts with `.asciz "` instead of just the string contents as the first byte?  If not, then maybe you can play some macro tricks to get the expansion of `#include "string.txt"`stringified.