# Is there a way in C to get a block of code as string in C?

Tags: c, macros

e.g.

```
const char* my_func_string = "int func(){"
                       " return 1; }";   //is there a way to do it automatically?
int func(){ 
    return 1;
}
```

func could be of multiple lines. And I want my_func_string to capture the change whenever I change func. It'd be better if it's captured at compile time because the executables may not find the source code

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to see a listing of a function you've previously written and compiled, or whether you want to execute arbitrary code in a string.  Both are difficult.

Comment: In C++, there is [`std::embed`'s proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1040r0.html) which might help.

Comment: Or you can run an external program to parse all the function definitions and put them in the respective variables in an additional file before compiling. Why would you need this feature?

Comment: @Jarod42 - it appears that the `std::embed` proposal is just for embedding static resources, not about embedding a compiler.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235175/how-do-i-add-contents-of-text-file-as-a-section-in-an-elf-file

Comment: @SteveFriedl: I meant: `auto my_func_string = std::embed("func.cpp");`. it requires indeed to split code in different files.

Answer (score 2):

The best option is writing an external script or code generator that preprocesses your code.

But, if you want a hack, use stringification:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s

#define MYFUNC int myfunc() { return 1; }

char * myfunc_string = xstr(MYFUNC);
MYFUNC

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n%d\n", myfunc_string, myfunc());
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
int myfunc() { return 1; }
1
```

This way you only have to write the function once, inside the `#define`.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, there's "a way", but it's not purely in C.  Going back a few decades you can do things like:

```
$ cat a.c.m4 
define(func,
``int func(void) {
        return 1;
};'')dnl

char *my_func_string = "func";
func
$ m4 a.c.m4 

char *my_func_string = "int func(void) {
        return 1;
};";
int func(void) {
        return 1;
};
```