# add some strings to an ELF binary after it has been built

Tags: elf

Is there any way that I can set up an ELF executable such that I can add a small table of keys and values to it after it has already been "built", and get access to those keys and values when the program inside the executable is running?

My use case is this: I am deploying a program together with some secrets. The environment I am deploying to does not have internet connectivity, so it cannot pull secrets from anywhere. I like the simplicity of deploying and running a single executable file. I want to avoid introducing multiple files that need to be pointed at one another. But on the other hand, I do not want to expose my secrets to my dev or build environments. What I would like to do is build the executable as per normal, then at the time of deployment, imbue the executable with the secrets, ideally by writing them into the executable itself.

Is it possible to read an ELF binary and add a new text section, or something like that? And then, when the program in the executable is running, can I get a pointer to the section with a certain name, in a way that lets me handle the situation where that section does not exist?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42238374/795053) is an absolute gem concerning details of elf binaries and linking, but before I go down that rabbit hole, I'm wondering: is there some more straightforward or more standard way to add some strings to an ELF executable after it has been built?

Comment: Feels like an incredibly awkward way to go about things, can you just use Environment Variables?

Comment: eh, what? Your application shouldn't have to worry about sections existing or not, unless you are manually parsing an ELF file, or doing some strict memory layout (retro embedded development?). Some details about target language/architecture would help to get useful answers. Can you just include placeholder string `var texty = "01234"` and replace the contents later (a guid or similar would make this easy)?

Answer (score 1):

> and get access to those keys and values when the program inside the executable is running

This seems trivial to achieve:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct KV {
  char key[40];
  int val;
} kv[100] = {"", 42};

int main()
{
  for (struct KV *p = &kv[0]; p->key[0] != '\0'; ++p) {
    printf("key: %s, value: %d\n", p->key, p->val);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This program will not print anything (the first `key` is empty), until you "imbue" it with your secrets.

Finding where the `kv[]` begins is trivial -- just use `nm a.out` and `readelf -WS a.out` (to find out the file offset to the `.data`). Once you know the file offset, overwrite the data there with your secrets, and voila.

P.S. You can also do this with `gdb --write ./a.out` for demonstration purposes.

```
./a.out
# no output as expected

gdb -q --write ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...

(gdb) p &kv[0]
$1 = (struct KV *) 0x404040 <kv>
(gdb) set var $1.key = "abc"
(gdb) set var $1.val = 1001

(gdb) p &kv[1]
$2 = (struct KV *) 0x40406c <kv+44>
(gdb) set var $2.key = "cde"
(gdb) set var $2.val = 2002
(gdb) q

$ ./a.out
key: abc, value: 1001
key: cde, value: 2002
```