# How to specify symbol name when creating objects from raw binary files using objcopy?

Tags: linker, binutils, object-files, symbol-table, objcopy

As described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235175/how-do-i-add-contents-of-text-file-as-a-section-in-an-elf-file), GNU `objcopy` can be used to create object files from arbitrary file content. This method can be used to embed resources into programs. However, the symbol name is generated by input file name.

For example, if you run:

```
objcopy --input binary --output elf64-x86-64 --binary-architecture i386:x86-64 myfile.txt myfile.o
```

The generated object file would contain `_binary_myfile_txt_start`, `_binary_myfile_txt_end` and `_binary_myfile_txt_size`, which simply replaces non-alphanumeric characters with `_`.

However, when I process files `foo.bar` and `foo_bar`, or even multiple `foo.bar` on different directories, the symbols would be same. So is there a way to manually specify the symbol in output object file to avoid conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that I can run `objcopy` to rename the symbol via `--redefine-sym` option. The only caveat is I have to run `objcopy` twice for each input file, once for creating the object file and once for rename symbols.

The `--redefine-sym` option can be specified multiple times, so the rename only needs to run `objcopy` once for all three `xxx_start` `x_end` and `xxx_size` symbols. The input file and output file to `objcopy` can be same, so you don't need to decide where to place another temp file.

Answer (score 1):

> However, when I process files foo.bar and foo_bar, or even multiple foo.bar on different directories,

It seems exceedingly unlikely that you will want to embed *both* `foo.bar` and `foo_bar` from a single directory. If you do, you can always make a copy (or a symlink) under a different name, and embed *that*.

The multiple directories also doesn't appear to be a real issue: if you use directory path, the name ends up as `_binary_relative_dir_foo_bar_start` or `_binary__absolute_dir_foo_bar_start`.

> So is there a way to manually specify the symbol in output object file to avoid conflict?

No, the name is hard-coded in `binutils/bfd/binary.c` [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=bfd/binary.c;h=c31ef3c2eca8954ae2ec771248df74c74e9ef041;hb=HEAD#l122).