Linker Fails To Resolve External Pointer
I am trying to compile the following files using gcc (arm-linux-musleabi-gcc (GCC) 9.4.0), but the reference to json_start does not get fixed up correctly and incorrectly ends up as an offset rather than a pc relative access (ie. 0x4762 instead of 0x5114762).
The idea is that the json contents get binned into the binary. Ideally we would use the #embed directive but the musl build does not support that yet. We did also consider .incbin but we would prefer not to add an assembly file simply to handle something that objcopy already purports to support. Additionally I would like to understand what exactly is happening here.
file.h
#ifndef __FILE_H__
#define __FILE_H__
#include <stddef.h>


typedef size_t (*strlen_fn)(const char *s);
#define strlen ((strlen_fn)Strlen)

extern const unsigned char * json_start;
#endif

file.c:
#include <file.h>

void *entry(void) __attribute__((section(".entry")));
void do_stuff(unsigned char *, void *);


void *entry(void) {
    do_stuff((unsigned char *)json_start, entry);
}

void do_stuff(unsigned char *json_start, void *entry) {
    json_start[0] = 0;
    return;
}

file.json:
{}

linker.ld
SECTIONS
{
    .text : 
    {
        *(.entry)
        *(.core)
        *(.text*)
        *(.rodata*)
        *(.data*)
        *(.bss*)
        *(.got*)
        *(COMMON)
    }
    /DISCARD/ : 
    {
        *(*)
    }
}

Currently I'm trying:
rm -r build
mkdir -p ./build
arm-linux-musleabi-objcopy -I binary -B arm -O elf32-littlearm ./file.json ./build/json.o
arm-linux-musleabi-objcopy --redefine-sym _binary___file_json_start=json_start ./build/json.o
arm-linux-musleabi-gcc -o ./build/file.o -c -fPIE -fno-builtin -ffreestanding -march=armv5t -Os -I . file.c
arm-linux-musleabi-gcc -o ./build/file -nostdlib -pie -T linker.ld ./build/file.o ./build/json.o -lgcc

I have also tried:
arm-linux-musleabi-gcc -r -o ./build/json.o -Wl,-b,binary file.json
arm-linux-musleabi-objcopy --redefine-sym _binary_file_json_start=json_start ./build/json.o

which is no better.
The assembly ends up looking like:
ldr r3,[r3,r2]
ldr r0,[r3,#0x0]
bl do_stuff

rather than
ldr r3,[r3,r2]
ldr r0,[r3,#0x0]
add r0, pc, r0
bl do_stuff

where r0 is json_start.
UPDATE:
I have figured out that its because json_start ends up in the GOT. My linker script just bins the GOT into the binary and none of the symbols get fixed up.

It is a perfect way of getting into trouble. :D

I think you should explain what you are doing here. "look at the commands" is not a good answer, as these are far from any regular workflow developers are dealing with on daily basis.

@EugeneSh. I would argue that this is an uncommon solution to a common problem/workflow. I can add an explanation though.

Have you looked at the resultant linker map file to see where json_start is located?
Also, I'm not sure I understand why json_start would be accessed relative to the PC and not a fixed address(It seems like compiling as position independent code would ensure no literal or variable is accessed relative to the pc).  Finally, wouldn't a more reliable mechanism be to convert the json file to a C array and compile it? (A brief search for binary objcopy suggests it's platform dependent and only works on some architectures)

@RussSchultz We don't use a linker map file since we are position independent. json_start is the only label that doesn't get accessed relative to pc. converting to a C array would not be more reliable since we also have binary data embedded and we would need to change the array every time we modify the file. What makes you think this behavior of objcopy is platform dependent? Even so, the linker seems to have no problem recognizing the object as valid at link time for our arm target here.

Hmm... I am not sure if someone who declares a pointer into .text and then casts away the const before passing it as non-const parameter into a function should be trusted with embedding JSON into an executable in the first place. Just sayin'. ;-)

@DevSolar That's just for demonstration purposes so that json_start doesn't get optimized out. Just sayin' ;).

@ChristopherWrogg conversion of binary files to C arrays is a very common build pattern.   Talk to the engineer responsible for the build environment and s/he'll know what to do.   If that person is you, then you should get to understand dependencies, makefiles (or cmake, or ninja, or whatever).   Regarding platform dependency of objcopy, I looked up 'objcopy binary' and basically each tool decorates names its own way.   Anyways, here's a working example for non-PIE, maybe follow what's going on there, then convert to PIE when you see it working?   https://stackoverflow.com/a/42238374/550235

@RussSchultz Conversion of binary files to C arrays is such an antipattern that gcc added the #embed directive specifically for this problem.

If you use objcopy (or the equivalent tool of non-Gnu toolsets) to create an object file with the content of a binary file, it has no type. The linker knows no types at all. You define by your extern declaration the type of the binary block. In contrast, #embed is limited to C23 compliant compilers or extended GCC, and to arrays of unsigned char.

Is it possible to have an object external to the current translation unit accessed PC relative? I played a bit around but only time-boxed. -- Would you mind to provide a [mre], optimally in Godbolt to experiment with? You might want to replace your JSON content with some example C string.

The definition of json_start might be wrong, did you try extern const unsigned char json_start[];?

If you're able to use a compiler with C23 features, you could just use the #embed directive.

For anyone still curious I'm fairly certain this is the same problem as the combination of -static-pie and -nostdlib.
